# Extremely Slow Migration Runtime Using Java, Hibernate, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We've been building and maintaining a webapp for 4 years with a back-end of Java, Hibernate and MySQL.  Sometimes the changes we make require complicated database migrations that I only know how to write in Java and our process is to push the code changes then run a Java app with the migration against our Production and QA servers.  Running the Java app against our entire database is getting extremely slow and can take many hours or even days.  Have other folks run into this problem and have a recommended solution?  Just searching a bit I've seen a database product Flyway and Migrate4j - have others used those and been happy with them?